# Error response from daemon: Get http://localhost:8185/v2/: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.5 vm.

I started a local registry. The compose file and docker file are as follows.

```
FROM registry

RUN apk add --no-cache apache2-utils

RUN mkdir /auth \
    && htpasswd -bnB admin admin > /auth/htpasswd
```

And the compose file is as follows.

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  basic:
    build: .
    image: registrywithbasicauth:dev
    ports:
      - 8185:5000
    environment:
      REGISTRY_AUTH: htpasswd
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: basic-realm
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: /auth/htpasswd
```

when I try to do docker login as follows

```
docker login localhost:8185 -u admin -p admin
```

it gives the following output.

> Error response from daemon: Get http://localhost:8185/v2/: net/http:
> request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

docker info gives the following.

```
vagrant@m1:~$ docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 3
 Server Version: 19.03.13
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: active
  NodeID: vl9dvflwc2ikdjnqkk20azwvy
  Is Manager: true
  ClusterID: 8me50zl43p03nnagqcf5p77sz
  Managers: 1
  Nodes: 1
  Default Address Pool: 10.0.0.0/8
  SubnetSize: 24
  Data Path Port: 4789
  Orchestration:
   Task History Retention Limit: 5
  Raft:
   Snapshot Interval: 10000
   Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
   Heartbeat Tick: 1
   Election Tick: 10
  Dispatcher:
   Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
  CA Configuration:
   Expiry Duration: 3 months
   Force Rotate: 0
  Autolock Managers: false
  Root Rotation In Progress: false
  Node Address: 192.168.99.201
  Manager Addresses:
   192.168.99.201:2377
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.15.0-112-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 1
 Total Memory: 985.1MiB
 Name: m1
 ID: G2DN:AW43:FLHA:OKHO:G25Q:CFEQ:UBNA:7FZH:UCF4:HUXZ:NMWF:UTEF
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: true
  File Descriptors: 40
  Goroutines: 155
  System Time: 2020-11-21T11:33:50.163810311Z
  EventsListeners: 0
 HTTP Proxy: http://proxy.example.com:80
 HTTPS Proxy: https://proxy.example.com:443
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: true
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: API is accessible on http://0.0.0.0:2375 without encryption.
         Access to the remote API is equivalent to root access on the host. Refer
         to the 'Docker daemon attack surface' section in the documentation for
         more information: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

I am not sure whats happening.

I looked at many references, but could not succeed loggin in so far.

Some of the references are as follows.

1. https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/3077
2. https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/docker-tutorial/
3. https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change the DNS to Google DNS server.

change the nameserver in the file `/cat/resolv.conf` to `8.8.8.8`

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```